# Glide not loading online Images

Tags: android, networking, android-glide

I am facing problem about loading a online image into Glide! I have tried those code:

My **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devX.meta"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
        // implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
        }
```

**NB: I can't Change my API Level**

Without Changing Api Level of gradle how to solve this?

This is the Glide Code Which I am calling From

**MainActivity**

```
Glide.with(this).load("https://animevaya.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/ic_launcher-web.png").placeholder(R.drawable.window).error(R.drawable.bg_white_text_red).into(ImgX);
```

Have any Solution?

Comment: please provide error message too that way we can help you

Comment: There are no Error When I open my app that firstly show placeholder then Error Holder!  I can't understanding where Error Occurred

Comment: What is your device API level, I recommend you install lower device android version 6.0 or 7.0 if it show it means you should config network_config because your app target android 28

Answer (score 0):

You can try with latest version

```
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

Then

```
 RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(this);
 RequestBuilder requestBuilder = requestManager.load("your_url");
 requestBuilder.into(imageViewOBJ);
```

### FYI

1. You are using **OLD** `compile`. Move to **`implementation`**.
2. Move to **`AndroidX`**.
3. **`compileSdkVersion`** should be 29.